# Single line Lambda and Run-time exceptions - Not compiling?

Tags: java, lambda, runtimeexception

I am working on single line lambda and run time exceptions.

I have tested following use cases and found statement **`1`** is not compiling where as statement **`2`** is compiling fine.

```
 new Thread(() -> throw new RuntimeException("test")); // 1
 new Thread(() -> new RuntimeException("test")); //2
```

Please help me understand why statement 1 is not compiling but statement two is compiling fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A lambda expression is defined (in [JLS 15.27. Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-LambdaExpression) ) as:

> **LambdaExpression**:
> LambdaParameters -> LambdaBody

A LambdaBody is defined as:

> **LambdaBody**:
> Expression
> Block

In both your lambda expressions, you don't use a block as the lambda body (that would require curly braces), which means you must be using an Expression.

Expression is defined as:

> Expressions can be broadly categorized into one of the following syntactic forms:
>
> - Expression names (§6.5.6)
> - Primary expressions (§15.8 - §15.13)
> - Unary operator expressions (§15.14 - §15.16)
> - Binary operator expressions (§15.17 - §15.24, and §15.26)
> - Ternary operator expressions (§15.25)
> - Lambda expressions (§15.27)

`new RuntimeException("test")` falls into the category of "Primary expressions", which includes object creations (the fact that the object being created is an `Exception` makes no difference). Therefore it's a valid lambda body.

On the other hand, `throw new RuntimeException("test")` doesn't fall into any of these categories, and therefore is not an expression.

In order for a lambda body to contain that statement, you must use a Block LambdaBody:

```
new Thread(() -> {throw new RuntimeException("test");});
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out the similarity between throw and return: you can't return in an email lambda body either, for the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

Line number 1 compiles if you change it to:

```
new Thread(() -> { throw new RuntimeException("test"); });
```

Curly braces can only be omitted for single statements.

The second line is a single expression which creates a new `RuntimeException`, but it has no effect apart from that.

See [Java Lambda Expressions Syntax Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax)

Comment: Why does the second expression work? According to the syntax it should be equal to `Runnable runnable = () -> {return new RuntimeException("test");}; new Thread(runnable);`, which doesn't compile.

Comment: @justgivememyicecream no, it's not the same as that. There is no implicit return, in the same way as it is fine to write `() -> System.out.println("")` in a lambda. The key thing is that it is [void-compatible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2).

Comment: @AndyTurner thinks for pointing that out. Added this to my answer

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to write the following as a statement:

```
new RuntimeException();
```

Creating and throwing the exception instance are separate things. As such, this does nothing useful; it just warms up the room a little bit.

This is exactly what you are doing in the second form.

Comment: I don't think so...the OP's second expression did not have a ";". According to [the lambda syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax), "If you specify a single expression, then the Java runtime evaluates the expression and then returns its value. "

Comment: Sorry, I tried running the code and the second thread indeed did not throw any exception. But why?

Comment: @justgivememyicecream if you do that *in a lambda which has to return a value*. If the return type is void, it doesn't return a value.

Comment: @justgivememyicecream "Creating and throwing the exception instance are separate things".

Comment: Does that mean that the result of the evaluation of a lambda expression varies based on the functional interface's return type? For example, it also works when I have a `@FunctionalInterface interface ExceptionSupplier{Exception supply();}` and do `ExceptionSupplier e = () -> new RuntimeException("test");`, in which case the same expression `new RuntimeException("test")` is evaluated as an implicit return.

Comment: @justgivememyicecream yes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this what you want:

```
new Thread(() -> { throw new RuntimeException("test"); }); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax of a lambda expression is:

```
(parameters) -> expression
```

or

```
(parameters) -> {statements;}
```

In your first statement, `throw new RuntimeException("test");` is a **statement** (more specifically, a [throw Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-ThrowStatement)), so it should be surrounded by brackets:

```
new Thread(() -> {throw new RuntimeException("test")});
```

In the second statement, `new RuntimeException("test")` is an **expression**, (more specifically, a [Class Instance Creation Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ClassInstanceCreationExpression)). That's why it works without the brackets and the semicolon.

================A little something additional====================

Here, the lambda expression `() -> new RuntimeException("test")` works with the `Runnable` interface whose return type is `void`. Actually, it could also work with something returning an `Exception`, e.g.:

```
  @FunctionalInterface interface ExceptionSupplier{Exception supply();} //another functional interface that it works with!

  ExceptionSupplier e = () -> new RuntimeException("test");
  System.out.println(e.supply()); //prints "java.lang.RuntimeException: test"
```

In this case, the very same expression is evaluated as

```
ExceptionSupplier e = () -> {return new RuntimeException("Test");};
```

This is because the expression `() -> new RuntimeException("test")` is both *void-compatible* and *value-compatible* (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2))

> A block lambda body is *void-compatible* if every return statement in the block has the form return;.
>
> A block lambda body is *value-compatible* if it cannot complete normally
>   (§14.21) and every return statement in the block has the form return
>   Expression;.

This answer has been inspired by both @AndyTurner and @Eran's answers.
Further complements are welcome.