# Inline lambda syntax for throwing Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, lambda

For a lambda that returns void, this is valid:

```
Runnable b = () -> System.out.println("3");
```

But this is not:

```
Runnable b = () -> throw new RuntimeException("3");
```

I know I can put it in a block with braces, but why is this not valid syntax for an inline lambda?

Comment: This seems very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625883/single-line-lambda-and-run-time-exceptions-not-compiling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `() -> foo` syntax defines the lambda's body as an expression ([JLS 15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)), so it makes perfect sense that `throw new RuntimeExpression("3")` wouldn't compile: that's a statement, not an expression. So the real question is, why does the println compile? After all, that's a statement, too.

JLS 15.27.3 says that:

> If the function type's result is void, the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block.

Neither of your examples are blocks (void-compatible or otherwise), so they have to be statement expressions. Those are defined in [JLS 14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) and include:

```
StatementExpression:
  Assignment 
  PreIncrementExpression 
  PreDecrementExpression 
  PostIncrementExpression 
  PostDecrementExpression 
  MethodInvocation 
  ClassInstanceCreationExpression
```

Note the MethodInvocation -- that's what lets your println lambda compile.

So in short: The first println compiles because it's a MethodInvocation form of a statement expression, and the throw does not compile because statement expressions do not include `throw`.

Note that all statement expressions are expressions (hence the name), so what this really boils down to is the fact that the println is actually an expression of type `void`, despite the fact that we only ever think of it as a statement. (In fact, the reason we normally think of it as a statement is that you can only ever use it as a statement expression, as mentioned in [JLS 15.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.1)).